# Отправка ссылки в коментарий вк

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Не могу разобраться как прикрепить ссылку в поле attachments
Не могу понять в каком формате отправить
есть обьект `link` и у него есть поля

> ```
> url — адрес ссылки;
> title — заголовок ссылки;
> description — описание ссылки;
> image_src — адрес превью изображения к ссылке (если имеется);
> preview_page — идентификатор wiki страницы с контентом для предпросмотра содержимого страницы, который может быть получен используя метод pages.get. Идентификатор возвращается в формате "owner_id_page_id";
> preview_url — адрес страницы для предпросмотра содержимого страницы.
> ```

я так понял,что делать запрос нужно в формате attachments=link url_title_description_previewpage_previewurl
не могу разобраться что вставить в поля preview_page и preview_url и правильно ли я понял формат запроса

` static void makeAComment(String ownerId,String newsId,String textComment,String apiToken,String attachments) throws IOException{

```
    String requestUrl = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.addComment?owner_id="
            + ownerId + "&post_id=" +newsId+"&text=" +textComment+"&attachments="+attachments+"&access_token=" + apiToken;
    System.out.println("request url: " + requestUrl);
    URL obj = new URL(requestUrl);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Sending 'GET' request to URL : " + requestUrl);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
    }`
```

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы ссылку дали на то, что используете...какие методы...и где их глянуть.......и что это - прикрепление к сообщению или к стене?.... и вообще то, что вы указали - это возвращаемые значения, а не отсылаемые...разве нет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский делаю комментарий к посту в группе, хочу прикрепить ссылку и не получаеться, по доке смотрел здесь - https://vk.com/dev/attachments_w

Comment: напишите ваш код, умоляю..... хочется видеть что вы делаете....откуда что берете и куда что кладете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил код

Answer (score 1):

Не надо никаких объектов, просто добавляете собственно саму ссылку в attachments как есть и всё. Описанный объект - это не при отправке, а при получении уже отправленного, его ВК создаст сам.

UPD: впрочем, как оказалось, конкретно в addComment это не работает, похоже на баг или недоработку ВК.

Comment: @ andreymal запрос&attachments=linkhttp://www.адрес&access_token=token вот такой формат?

Comment: @Sasha никаких link тоже не надо, просто `attachments=http://www.адрес`. Ну и, разумеется, не забыть экранировать спецсимволы.

Comment: @ andreymal делаю как вы говорите, но  в ответ получаю   attachments should by specified

Comment: @Sasha выложите вы ваш код в вопрос... посмотреть что вы делаете... Потому что гадание на кофейной гуще еще не все освоили

Comment: @ АлексейШиманский https://api.vk.com/method/wall.addComment?  owner_id=-50978521&post_id=2468&from_group=0&attachments=https:\/\/www.google.com.ua\/?gws_rd=ssl&ref=as&access_token=123456789

Comment: @Sasha Экранирование то, почитайте матчасть про экранирование данных в ссылках (и разберитесь, зачем оно вообще нужно)

Comment: @ andreymal  http%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2F  
вот в каком формате я шлю адрес, ничего не помогает

Comment: @Sasha а вот теперь это действительно похоже на баг ВК и есть смысл написать в Поддержку.